# error note when trying to latex a list of figure captions

Tags: floats, captions

What does @xdblarg mean as an error note with respect to a list of figures?

Comment: It might be a missing closing brace, but we need the *exact* error message and ideally a complete little document allowing us to reproduce the poblem.

Comment: Can you please provide 1) the entire error message, and 2) a complete and minimal document that reproduces the error? Thanks :-)

Comment: @Closers: please give the OP some time to react before voting to close. 30 minutes is not too much time.

Comment: The error message is most likely produced by a fragile command in the caption text. Without seeing it, it's impossible to say more.

Answer (score 1):

`\@xdblarg` is an internal command that handles the optional argument to `\caption` making `\caption{zzz}` the same as `\caption[zzz]{zzz}`.

So either you have a misplaced `{}` or `[]` or (more likely) a fragile command in the main argument, that should be prefixed with `\protect`